# Should primefaces be a jboss module? or just an WAR lib?

Tags: primefaces, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, jboss-eap-6

We have started using primefaces with JBoss EAP 6.2 in our new projects?

I noticed that we use it configured as module in JBoss as opposed to just a WAR lib.

Some [examples online](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/how-to-use-primefaces-with-jboss-713.html#.UzS7wvmSwg0) show it to be used as a module too.

I'm a bit worried as this will tie us to a one specific version of the library for the whole instance.

Which one is the right approach?

- Module
- War lib
- EAR lib (don't think this would work)

Comment: "I'm a bit worried as this will tie us to a one specific version of the library for the whole instance." - you said it all. war lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested primefaces as a WAR lib and it worked fine.

I reckon this would be a cleaner approach allowing us to use multiple versions in different projects.

Answer (score 0):

Why use different versions of the library?

If application development and server control are the responsibility of the internal team of the company I suggest you use Primefaces as JBOSS module.

This creates a pattern of development since the projects are new.

You have to maintain a pattern of architecture and the same level of team knowledge.